# AngularJS data disappears after refresh and comes back after changing page

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a factory with stored data from $http requests.
My issue is, when I'm reloading the page, all the data is gone (empty table).
But as soon as I switch my current page (different route) the data is back again.

What do I need to change for the data being displayed after the page has been reloaded?

This is my factory:

```
'use strict';

app.factory('dataFactory', function ($http) {
    var dataFactory = {};

    $http.get("data/hiragana.json").success(function(response){
        dataFactory.hiragana = response;
    });

    $http.get("data/katakana.json").success(function(response){
        dataFactory.katakana = response;
    });

    return {
        getHiraganaTable: function(){
            return dataFactory.hiragana;
        },
        getKatakanaTable: function(){
            return dataFactory.katakana;
        }
    };
});
```

This is my controller:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('HiraganaTableCtrl', function (dataFactory, $scope) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma',
      'dataFactory',
      '$scope'
    ];

    $scope.hiraganaTable = dataFactory.getHiraganaTable();

  });
```

And this is my view:

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
    <tbody data-ng-repeat="group in hiraganaTable">
        <tr>
            <td data-ng-repeat="hiragana in group.Hiragana" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="{{hiragana.Romaji}}" data-container="body">{{hiragana.Symbol}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried this out, but it didn't help. Data still disappearing after refreshing the page.

Comment: $http.get is an ajax call. So, you cannot just do $scope.hiranganaTable = dataFactory.getHiranganaTable() because the initial value of dataFactory.hirangana will always be empty array. You need to set the value inside a callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're trying to access async code in a sync way. The `$http` method returns a promise. So you could try something like this:

Service:

```
'use strict';

app.factory('dataFactory', function ($http) {
    return {
        getHiraganaTable: function() {
            return $http.get("data/hiragana.json");
        },
        getKatakanaTable: function() {
            return $http.get("data/katakana.json");
        }
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('HiraganaTableCtrl', function (dataFactory, $scope) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma',
      'dataFactory',
      '$scope'
    ];

    dataFactory.getHiraganaTable().then(function(res) {
      $scope.hiraganaTable = res.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful. Is the .then equivalent to the .success function?

Comment: They are a bit different. The `success()` returns the original promise from `$http` and `then()` a new promise. The `then()` has the advantage it allows you to chain other promises and I also find it better to create unit tests. You might want to have a look at this [post](http://goo.gl/a6NmCS).